# spectrum of unitary operator in Hilbert space

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

How to find the spectrum of unitary operator in Hilbert Space?

My Attempt:

As $||T||=1$ therefore for $\lambda\in \sigma(T) $, $ |\lambda| \leq 1$ and also $ T^*=T^{-1}$, that implies for as $\lambda\in \sigma(T) $,    $\frac1{ \lambda}\in \sigma(T^{-1})= \sigma(T^*) $, and as $||T||=||T^*||=1$,
hence $|\lambda|\geq1 $, which implies $|\lambda|=1$. From this i got $\sigma(T^*)$ $\subset S^1$. But how to show otherside containment?

Comment: The spectrum will almost never be all of $S^1$, so the containment is usually strict.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no "otherside containment". Any compact subset of the complex plane is the spectrum of a normal operator. So any compact subset of the circle can be the spectrum of a unitary.

For a couple of particular examples, the identity is a unitary with spectrum ${1}$. And $$U=\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&i\end{bmatrix}$$ is a unitary with spectrum $\sigma(U)=\{1,i\}$.